# PHP DOM challenge - parsing problematic javascript

Tags: php, javascript, dom

This is a wierd problem, and I can't see an easy solution.

If you attempt to use DOM to parse a document that has a `</head>` tag contained within a javascript function, it doesn't work correctly. It takes the `</head>` inside the javascript function as the closing `</head>` tag.

I have been wrestling with this for hours - any ideas?

```
<?php
$contents =
<<<EOF
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
<script>function myFunc() { var myVar = "<head></head>"; } </script>
</head>
<body><p>This is a test</p></body>
</html>
EOF;

//GET CONTENT & LOAD INTO DOM
$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$doc->loadHTML($contents);

//STRIP OUT THE JAVASCRIPT
$scripts = $doc->getElementsByTagName('script');
$length = $scripts->length;
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
    $scripts->item(0)->parentNode->removeChild($scripts->item(0));
}

echo htmlentities($doc->saveHTML());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Common Javascript issue: Use this instead:

```
var myVar = "<head><\/head>";
```

Comment: It's not really a JS issue, it's a browser parsing issue. This keeps the parser from thinking your head tag is being closed within the script. The more common way to do this is using `"<head></ " + "head>"`

Comment: While `"<head></ " + "head>"` may be more common, it is no less correct than `"<head><\/head>";` and I'd argue that the `\/` is easier to read.  Both accomplish the same thing .. break up the string literal of `</head>`

Comment: Jeremy, thank you so much - I corrected the issue by changing to `<\/head>` as you suggested and it works brilliantly. I also noticed that adding the line:
    `$contents = str_replace('</head>', "<\/head>", $contents);`
also works brilliantly. I am guessing this isn't correct in some way, but it works and avoids the need for me to search & replace all my old HTML documents.

Comment: @whizzkid -- You don't want to change the HTML `</head>` to `<\/head>`.  Just the ones that are wrapped inside of Javascript strings.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher I didn't say it was wrong, just that there's another more instantly recognizable way.

Answer (score 0):

You can escape characters that you don't want interpreted.  For example:

```
var myVar = "\x3chead\x3e\x3c/head\x3e";
console.log(myVar);
```

Will create "<head></head>" without actual < > characters.